# "Error occurred" (500) when collecting basic information about your Sitecore installation

Tags: sitecore-api, packages, support

I have raised a ticket on the Sitecore support portal. They asked me to provide basic information about my Sitecore site from each instance in your environment. Check the article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/406145 for details.

When I am following instruction it's throwing me error in the console in `main.bundle.js:1`

[image]

After clicking on a **Collect** button it's throwing me below error:

> Error occurred. Check browser console for details.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the Sitecore logs that might explain the 500 Server Error being thrown in your second screenshot above ?

Comment: Hello andyp, unfortunately, there is no error in a log file on path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*****.Local\App_Data\logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investing and raised a ticket to Sitecore support portal, I have found below solution:

1) Package name or ticket number should not have any illegal characters like `*` symbol etc.

2) Open the "...App_Data\diagnostics\support_package" folder and remove all the existing packages from there.

3) Now again try to collect support package via the "Support Package" admin page one more time with the default package name and check it will work.

For more detials: [Collect basic information about Sitecore installation](https://himmatsinghdulawat.wordpress.com/2019/05/16/collect-basic-information-about-sitecore-installation/)